# What is the right approach to implement payable fallback function?

Tags: solidity, tokens, crowdsale

I am implementing crowdsale smart contract to accept ether and invoke ERC20 smart contract to assign tokens count calculated depending on the amount of ether invested.

I heard that just implementing default payable fallback is not right approach as that doesn't prevent customers from sending ether directly from exchange shared wallet accounts.

```js
function() payable {
        
}
```

What is the right approach then to implement a payable fallback (apart from *throw* there) in crowdsale contracts so that customers could only send ether via MEW, Metamask and other private wallets?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the `fallback` function has a stipend of 2300 gas when it comes to internal `sends` and `transfers`, from one smart contract to another. This happens because `send` and `transfer` haven't got a mechanism to set the gas spent so they are by default limited to 2300(on the other hand `call` consumes as much gas as needed). So they still trigger code execution, but the called contract is only given a stipend of 2,300 gas which is currently only enough to log an event.

If you receive ether from an external account I believe there is no gas limit for your `send` or `transfer`. So theoretically, if you accept ether only from external accounts you could use the `fallback` method. I believe the best practice is to `revert` any calls to the `fallback` and simply add a buy function that is `payable`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable those kind of transaction only you should check for tx.origin as well in order to exclude any possible different invocation of your fallback.

```
require(tx.origin == msg.sender, “EOA direct transfer not detected”);
```

as first line of your fallback can be enough.

On the other hand this make your fallback not usable for manipulation by malicious contract as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to implement a Crowdsale suggest you check the various types available in OpenZeppelin:
https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/crowdsales